Movie where man pays hitman to assassinate a work colleague but (due to mistaken identity) has his daughter killed instead
I can't remember the name of a movie I watched a number of years ago.
There was a dad who was annoyed that his daughter (maybe it was Scarlett Johansen, not sure) was dating his office mate/boss, so he hired a hitman to kill the guy as he leaves a Christmas Party. He tells the murderer that he's wearing an elf/dwarf/Santa hat. Meanwhile the dad's daughter left the Christmas party before the intended target, and was also wearing the hat, so the hitman killed the daughter. The father realizes that the hitman killed the wrong person and goes to his storage unit and opens the black body bag and sees his own daughter inside. Please advise as to the name of this movie. 

What year did you see this movie, language, country? Was it in the theaters or on tv or tape?

A few years ago maybe on Netflix or online it was in English

That's basically the story from Verdi's opera Rigoletto.  The search for a recent film adaptation yields Rick, (2003).

Rick, an executive at Image, is a jerk to a woman applying for a job.
  That evening, he's out for drinks with his much younger boss, Duke,
  and the same women is their waitress. Rick's continued rudeness leads
  to her getting fired. She puts a curse on him. A potential rift with
  Duke quickly surfaces; Rick is approached by the hail-fellow Buck, who
  runs His Own Company, offering to rid Rick of Duke. At dinner later
  that night, Rick and Duke's paths cross again; this time Rick is with
  his stunning and beloved daughter, Eve, a student who has a secret
  relationship with Duke. All paths lead to the office holiday party.





@DanielStowers Don't know, didn't see it.  They're in the opera, though.
